# TextView cannot intent to another class even it is not null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview

I have Activity A and B. 
Activity A has `textView` and a `button`.
Activity B has one `textView` and one `editText`.

What I trying to achieve is let the `c` in Activity A clickable if it is not null.

When it is in Activity A, it display `null`. When I click the `button` to intent B and return `result` and `name` to A, it should display `not null` and can `intent` to `EditClaims.java` if `c` is clicked.

But the problem now is it **didn't** display `not null` when it is return `result` and `name` from B to A and not `intent` to `EditClaims.java` when `c` is click.

So this is how the activity's flow should look like

Activity A >> display null >> Button click >> Go to B >> return `result` and `name` from B  to A >> display not null >> go to `EditClaims.java` if `c` is clicked.

```
      String result="";
                String name=""
                 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
                  View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.claims, container, false);
                  c = (TextView) claims.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
                  Button button1 = (Button) claims.findViewById(R.id.button10);

                  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fk + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    AlertDialogRadio(a1);


                }
            });

     public void AlertDialogRadio(final int k) {
             final CharSequence[] ClaimsModel = {"B", "C", "D"};

            AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alt_bld.setTitle("Select a Claims");
            alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(ClaimsModel, -1, new DialogInterface
                    .OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (item == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), B.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    } else if (item == 1) {...} 
                                   .....

                    });

            }
                 if ((name != null && name.trim().length() > 0) && (result != null && result.trim().length() > 0)) { // check whether c is null or not null
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),  "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditClaims.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                        }else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),  "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }




                            }
                        });
                 return claims;
                    }

        @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  int button = data.getIntExtra("k1", 0); 
 {

                if (button == 1) {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        case 0:
                            result = data.getStringExtra("text"); // return from B
                            name = data.getStringExtra("a"); //return from B
                            as=Long.parseLong(result);
                            c.setText("            " + name + "------" + "RM " + result);
                            break;
```

**Activity B**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.B);
        txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText36);
        txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView57);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
        addListenerOnButton();


        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // save button
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                a = "Project";
                text = txt.getText().toString();
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Are you able to read the values in onActivityResult() ? What is button == 1 ?

Comment: @sr09 Ya, it can.The `result` and `name` can display on c.

Comment: @sr09 I just show some part of the code in Activity A. But what I'm trying to achieve is let the c `clickable` if it is not null

Comment: You should really start giving more meaningful names to your variables

Comment: Also, I don't understand your code, what is this:
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  int button = data.getIntExtra("k1", 0); 
 {
Also, you check button value, and I don't see that you set it in Activity B, even though your remark says:  return from B, when this value is 1.
Your code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @UdiIdan Thanks for your response. I have solved it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 c.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View v) {
                                     if ((name != null && name.trim().length() > 0) && (result != null && result.trim().length() > 0)) {
                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "not null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditClaims.class);
                                                 startActivity(intent);


                                         }
                                     else {
                                         Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     }
                                 }
                                     } );
```

It will be works everytime the textView is clicked.